# PDO extension configuration - I keep getting PDOException "could not find driver" in my PHP application

Tags: php, pdo, server-configuration

In a PHP application that I wrote, I keep getting an error that says:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with message 'exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /home/diftx/public_html/dol/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.1/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php:239 Stack trace: #0 /home/diftx/public_html/dol/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.1/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php(239): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'diftx_skcin7', 'thePassword', Array) #1 /home/diftx/public_html/dol/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.1/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php(101): ActiveRecord\Connection->__construct(Object(stdClass)) #2 /home/diftx/public_html/dol/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.1/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/ConnectionManager.php(33): ActiveRecord\Connection::instance('mysql://diftx_s...') #3 /home/diftx/public_html/dol/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.1/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Table.php(103): ActiveRecord\ConnectionManager::get_connection(NULL) #4 /home/diftx/public_html/dol/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.1/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Tabl in /home/diftx/public_html/dol/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.1/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php on line 241
```

Based on this message, I did some research about PDO and can't seem to figure out.

Here is a screenshot from my phpinfo() showing PDO information:

[image: Screenshot from my phpinfo() showing PDO information]

When I log into the server via PuTTY and type "php -m" a list of modules appear. In the list is both entries for PDO and pdo_sqlite.

I am somewhat new to server configuration and I simply cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong to set this up. Help!

Comment: Are you trying to use PDO with `MySQL`? It appears your server only had the drivers for `sqlite` and not `MySQL`.

Comment: Please include the entire error you get from your code

Comment: How is your PDO connection configured? Check if its [DSN is correct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php).

Comment: Hey guys. I ended up figuring it out. Turns out I had PDO configured, but I didn't have PDO_MySQL configured which was the problem. I read a bunch of things about this and it seems that I didn't realize until now that PDO and PDO_MySQL are two different things. That was what I didn't understand. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @fike or skcin7: could you add this as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Just like to answer this (I commented the solution). You do not have the required drivers for PDO to work with MySQL. You need to install them before you can use MySQL with PDO.